# How do I make sure all the Teen Girl Squad girls die?

Tags: cl-gm-attractive-people

I am playing Strong Bad's Cool Game for Attractive People, and have the option of playing a Teen Girl Squad mini-game.

I know I have to set up the story the right way, using object at the right times so that all the girls die gristly deaths, but I am having trouble figuring out the order of things. I know using hairspray on a girl before they talk to the basketball player kills off one of them, and giving the basketball to the player kills off another, but beyond that, I am at a loss.

How do I make sure all the girls die?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, find the [4 hidden cards](http://www.ps3trophies.com/forums/showwiki.php?title=Strong-Bads-Cool-Game-for-Attractive-People-Episode-1-Trophy-Guide):

> You will need the shovel (located in the room with the Poopsmith in the King of Town's castle) and the Black Metal Detector (located in the room with the fun machine in Strong Bad's house.)
>
> - Megaphone: Buried at the track.
> - Book: Buried in Strong Badia
> - Candy Bar: Dig up the loose dirt by Marzipan's house and pour Total Load down the hole.
> - Car Keys: Use the shovel with the car in the area with Strong Badia, Bub's, the Snap Shak, and The Stick.

Then, use the following procedure:

> Scene 1 (before the game)
>   Use the car keys with Whats Her Face, and use the basketball with Cheerleader
>
> Scene 2 (walking)
>   Use the book with So and So, and use sunscreen with The Ugly One
>
> Scene 3 (at the game)
>   Use the candy bar with The Ugly One, and use the megaphone with Cheerleader.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to go about killing them...

But if you want to get the high score (most comical), you'll probably want to use the secret cards (use the metal detector).

Scenes 1, 2: Use the car on *What's Her Face*. Then use items that will bypass the rest of these scenes without making Strong Bad groan (perfume, ring tone, suntan lotion).

**DO NOT** use the hairspray as this will automatically kill the girl you use it on when scene 3 starts, but not in a way that will achieve maximum comical effect.

Scene 3: You get three actions in the last scene. Use the megaphone on *Cheerleader*, the book on *So-and-so*, and the candy bar on *The Ugly One*.

You get a cool roach card for getting the best score~